# how to ignore files in kiln/mercurial using tortoise hg "that are part of the repository"

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg, kiln

We use tortoise hg with Kiln. In my vs 2010 c# project there are some files that are part of the repository but I would like tortoise hg to ignore them when I make a commit.
For eg., say in a login screen I may hard code the userid, password for testing.  I dont really want this file considered during a commit. I understand .hgignore file but this really works for files that are not part of the repo. Any trick in tortoise hg to **ignore files that are part of the repo** ? (so they do not show up as modified (M) during a commit.) thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always use a combination of .hgignore and `BeforeBuild` (in the .csproj file) for things like this.

In one of my pet projects, I have the following setup:

`App.config` contains my real hardcoded user id and password for testing.
`App.config.example` is identical, but with fake data like "dummy_user" and "dummy_pw".

`App.config` is **not** part of the repository, **and** it's ignored (in `.hgignore`).
`App.config.example` is part of the repository.

Then, I have the following in the `BeforeBuild` target in the .csproj file of my solution:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Copy
    Condition="!Exists('App.config')"
    SourceFiles="App.config.example" 
    DestinationFiles="App.config"/>
</Target>
```

All this together has the following effect:

- the config file with the real data can never be accidentally committed to the repository, because it's ignored
- the repository only contains the config file with the example data
- if someone else clones the repository to his machine, he won't have the "real" config file...but if it's missing, it will be automatically created before the first build by Visual Studio / MSBuild by simply copying the `.example` file (and then he can just put **his** real login data into the newly created `App.config` file).
- if an `App.config` with real hardcoded user data already exists, it won't be overwritten when building because the BeforeBuild event will only happen if `App.config` does **not** already exist

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Christian is the right one, but I want to mention that TortoiseHg supports what you want with their [Auto Exclude List](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/settings.html#commit).

One problem with an exclude list is that it cannot work with merges: you must commit all files when you merge and so you'll have to do a little dance with shelve, merge, commit, and unshelve.

Comment: Does it support wildcards? A simple test indicates that it doesn't and I need to list out every file by name but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a TortoiseHG commit, there is a list of files with checkboxes by them. Deselect the files you do not want comitted.

Or, on the command line, do a commit of the form `hg commit --exclude "pattern"`, where pattern is defined in the hg man page.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I do right now but sometimes I forget to uncheck that box you mention since the file I do not want committed is buried in the middle of whole bunch of files I want committed -- and hence this question :-). thanks

Comment: @Gullu: I have found the command line the best approach for more complicated operations in hg. I would suggest a "safecommit.bat" file which excludes the files that have the sensitive data.

Comment: ok. If nothing else works I will venture into the dark side (command line). thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [hg forget](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#forget).