# Is it possible to add only a few lines of a python script to .gitignore?

Tags: python, git

I would like to leave out a few lines of my python script from each commit that I do, for example this line:

DEBUG_OFFSET = 600

as I change this value every time, depending on from which frame I want to start a video, and I change this value every time, so I don't changes on values like this to be tracked, only on the rest of the code.

Is such a thing possible?

I know that is possible to use something like git add --patch  like on this topic:

[Commit only part of a file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git)

but this is very time consuming to do every time that I make a new commit, so I was thinking of something done automatically, more like adding just a portion of a file to the .gitignore, or something like this.

Any recommendation please :) ?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered loading this value from another file?

Comment: The best way may be to load that value from another file. Either a config file or a Python module that just contains configuration. Then you can just exclude that file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171275/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976900/7976758

Comment: To be clear, the answer to your title question is no, you can't ignore part of a file with .gitignore. As suggested in comments and the current answer you can split out the lines in question into a new file and ignore that.

Comment: Excellent! the solution  was indeed to save all the config values to a file, like a json or yaml and change this config files, but keep the code the same.
Many thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the value in another file in different formats.
One way is to create a `.env` file, add .env to .gitignore, and change the value as needed.

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

create a file called `.env`

put the value inside .env:

```
DEBUG_OFFSET = 600
```

Add it to gitignore
Load the required value in python file as follows:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load .env file
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".env")

# Assign it to variable
DEBUG_OFFSET = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
if DEBUG_OFFSET:
    DEBUG_OFFSET  = int(DEBUG_OFFSET)
```

Then, you can change the value of DEBUG_OFFSET inside `.env` as needed