How to automate git pull in GitHub Actions without overwriting server-specific configuration files?
I am using GitHub Actions to deploy my application to a cloud server (Digital Ocean Droplet). The issue I am facing is related to my config.json file that contains database credentials. The version of config.json in my GitHub repository has placeholder values, while the one on the server has actual credentials that should not be overwritten during a git pull.
Here's the relevant part of my GitHub Actions YAML workflow:
name: Deploy to Droplet

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Trigger deployment on push to the main branch

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Install sshpass
      run: sudo apt-get install sshpass

    - name: Deploy to Droplet
      run: |
        sshpass -p "${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }}" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@208.189.185.180 << 'EOF'
          cd /root/automation
          git pull origin main
          # Restart your app or perform other necessary steps
          # Example: systemctl restart your-app
        EOF

When I run this, git pull results in a conflict because the config.json file in the repository differs from the one in the server. Manually resolving conflicts each time isn’t feasible.
I want to automate the deployment process while ensuring the config.json file on the server is not overwritten or replaced during git pull.
I've considered:

Adding the config.json file to .gitignore, but this prevents it from being updated via Git if needed in the repository.
Using git stash to save local changes, but reapplying the stash might introduce conflicts.

What's the best practice to handle such configuration files while using GitHub Actions for deployments?
Is there an approach that allows me to merge updates from the repository while preserving server-specific configurations automatically?

"Adding the config.json file to .gitignore, but this prevents it from being updated…" Nope, Git doesn't ignore committed/tracked files even if the file is listed in .gitignore. "What's the best practice to handle such configuration files…?" The best practice is not track configuration files in Git. Track a template: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397905/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+configuration+file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397180/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976900/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+machine-specific+configuration+file

I have a few suggestions that apply depending whether Digital Ocean Droplets preserve files between deployments.
If the Droplets have a filesystem with files that are not deleted when a deployment puts files to the Droplet, my suggestion would be to have a version of your configuration file with the correct non-repo tracked credentials in a special filename on the target installation server that is copied to the filename that the Droplet application code expects to load.  That file rename operation would then be done by one of the deployment actions.
If the Droplets create a completely new filesystem with each deployment, then there should be some other kind of configuration built into the Digital Ocean Droplets hosting service that allows something like environment variables where you can put credentials that are not cleared by new deployments.  The environment variables method involves a slightly different method for loading credentials.  You can use environment variables to detect that a deployment is running on a development or official server to then run different methods for loading credentials depending on the environment.
Some of the user phd's linked SO posts are sort of like these suggestions but I am looking to score a SO points to enable commenting.  If you have more questions, I would like to help but cannot comment.
