# SQL Server 2008 what DataType to store a hashpassword in

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently building a login process and decided to store my user password in database with a hashpassword combined with a salt. Just wondering what datatypes to store the hashpassword and salt is Varchar or NVarchar sufficient ?

EDIT : Link where I am basing this on
[storing passwords in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876342/storing-passwords-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash of your passwords should be of uniform string length and represented as either hex or base64 text (or some other, single-byte-per-character representation.)

**EDIT** (You just need the char type per the uniform length of hash output!)

So **char** will suffice.

Comment: Grand, just a question where I have the hash and salt stored in DB. And a user comes along and enters in his username and password. I first have to retrieve the salt from the database, and then use this value to create the hash with the user entered password which I then check against the hash value in DB ?

Comment: That's correct. At some point you have to combine the salt (from the db or some other source) with the user's pwd, hash it and do your comparison. You can also choose to do the this in a stored procedure which would increase security since you would not have to take the salt out of the db. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft use `Nvarchar` in when we use SQL membership, have a look the below image

[image]

Comment: Grand, just a question where I have the hash and salt stored in DB. And a user comes along and enters in his username and password. I first have to retrieve the salt from the database, and then use this value to create the hash with the user entered password which I then check against the hash value in DB ?

Comment: Why not use build in ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and Roles Tutorial Series ? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx

Comment: What is the `PasswordFormat` in this image?

Answer (score 1):

use the `varchar` datatype

-- blah blah blah --

I need 30 characters to post a reply