# SQL Server, how to make login not repeatable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hello I wonder if there is way to disable repeating value in SQL Server 2012. I don't want several people to have the same login. As a primary key I am using ID. Should I change primary key from ID to Login ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Declare the login to be unique.

Or, equivalently, create a unique index on login:

```
create unique index table_login on table(login);
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should never store a password as plain text in the database.  Store an encrypted string if the password must be recoverable, but better yet store a salted hash of the password.

You could enforce your rule by creating a unique constraint on the Login column.

Comment: I did make some research, maybe you know some good tutorial with example ?

Comment: For a reference on hash/salting a password, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876342/storing-passwords-in-sql-server