# creating a password field in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, passwords

i have to create a password field for my Diver table,
the password has to be exactly 8 characters, and only numbers (0-9) and letters (a-z) are
allowed. how do i do that?

i tried:
    create table tblDiver
    (
    DiverNumber int primary key,
    DiverPassword char(8) not null CHECK (DiverPassword like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]        [0-9][0-9]')
    )
but of course it only gives me to put only numbers.. i want letters also

Comment: **Why are you storing passwords**?

Comment: You should be encrypting your passwords, not storing them in an unencrypted format. [This answer explains more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/876397/1048425). You can do this using `LIKE '[0-9|A-Z][0-9|A-Z]...`etc but just because you can doesn't mean you should. I strongly recommend that you validate the password on the client side, and stored the encrypted password.

Comment: this is for my home exercise :) i am a student and these our demands.. just beginners :)

Comment: BTW.. your suggestion doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save your passwords unencrypted in a database! NEVER!

but the regex expression you want is

```
like '[abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789][abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvzkwy0123456789]')
```

MSSQL as a fairly poor regex...

Comment: ALTER TABLE tblDiver
ADD CHECK (DiverPassword like ('[1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z][1-9a-z]'))