# Plain text encryption issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, cryptography

I have a database column filled with plain text. The managers decided that it is too risky to store passwords in a database as plain text. So the problem is, that I need to transfer all values in that given column to encrypted text and of course modify the business logic in C#. From know on the program should read the encrypted value from the database, decrypt the data and work with it, and of course if a new user registers I need to store the ecrypted value in the database. (But this does not a problem.)
So is there a proper and secure way to encrypt this whole column (which is already in use as plain text) without breaking the behavior of the software?

Comment: Its equally bad to store encrypted passwords.  You should be storing *hashed* passwords: [storing passwords in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876342/storing-passwords-in-sql-server)

Comment: Do you ever do anything with passwords from the DB other than validate them? (For example, do you ever email a customer their current password?)

Comment: Instead of encrypting/decrypting password, use the `PasswordHasher` class from asp.net to generate hashed versions of the entered password. You can also use the class to verify a password, without generating the exact same hash again. See this article: [PasswordHasher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Update your code locally, stop your services, hash all passwords in that column (do not encrypt as said above), publish updated code to server, start your services back.

Comment: You should read this: [Why your app’s security design could affect sales of Acai berries - Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/why-your-apps-security-design-could/)

Comment: Why would you email a customer their password? Don't do that. If they forget their password make them reset it, don't email it to them...

Comment: @JacobH we left Sprint many many years ago because every time we'd call "customer service" the first thing they did after verification was 'remind' us what our password was. Yikes!

Comment: Please fix your spelling: when you write _ecrypted_, do you mean "decrypted" or "encrypted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create new column like `hash_pwd`;

2) Fill it with hashed equivalent of current password;

3) Change software to work with hash, not plain password;

4) Drop or clear the old column with plain passwords.

PS: It is good idea to store not simple hash (MD5/SHA) of password but add static string like `HASH( plain_password + "my_string" )`. This will protect the database from hash-dictionary hacks - e.g. if I know the result of `HASH( "123456" )` and can find all users using password `123456`.

Comment: Using MD5 or SHA1 for secure hashes is not a good idea at all. Use strong hashing algorithms with preferably a random salt.