# C# SQL SERVER - Cannot convert nvarchar to text?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a problem with a huge project that I am working on. I never had this problem before but it started occurring today. Any fixes?

error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.'

I don't understand what It means. I don't want to have an sql injection so I am using parameters.. But it still gives errors.

Please ask me if you need me to describe something... This is like my 5th post.

```cs
            using (SqlCommand StrQuer = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=@userid AND password=@password", connection))
            {
                StrQuer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", username.Text.ToLower().Trim());
                StrQuer.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", obf.Obfuscate(password.Text).ToString());
                SqlDataReader dr = StrQuer.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.username = username.Text.ToLower();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.username = obf.Obfuscate(password.Text);
                    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\howcoolitisX");
                    key.SetValue("username", username.Text.ToLower());
                    key.SetValue("password", obf.Obfuscate(password.Text));
                    key.Close();
                    Form executor = new Loader();
                    executor.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
```

Comment: forgot to say! the obfuscate function just does a base64 obfucation ```cs     class Obfuscation
    {
        public string Obfuscate(string source)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source)).ToString();
        }```

Comment: The `text` data type is not appropriate for a password, you should change it to `nvarchar`. As an aside, base64 encoding does not provide any security.

Comment: I know. Base64 decoders are online. that's not what im worried about. Im worried about the sql not working atm. But what do you mean change it to nvarchar, the code or database?

Comment: I mean the database.

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.username = obf.Obfuscate(password.Text);` ???  Typo? Or are the users forced to set their username as the password?

Comment: typo but thx for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first I'd say that you should probably take a look at how can passwords be stored **[securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876342/storing-passwords-in-sql-server).**

And as for the issue at hand there are multiple solutions

1. Either [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert) the parameters in SQL

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username= CAST(@userid as text) AND password= CAST(@@passwordas text)", connection)
```

2. Or use [Parameters.Add instead of Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-addstring-object-and-parameters-addwithvalue) and set the parameter [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.8) explicitly.

```
StrQuer.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Text);
command.Parameters["@userid"].Value = username.Text.ToLower().Trim();
```

3. Or if you can easily change the database then by all means do as [Crowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111333/c-sharp-sql-server-cannot-convert-nvarchar-to-text/59111515#comment104453899_59111333) suggested and change columns to `nvarchar` as `text` is an [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) datatype

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: I like the option: change to "Parameters.Add(parameter, SqlDbType)" +1

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'm not looking for storing them securely because there's something else that will happen before this get's released the c# code itself will be obfuscated so yeah.